# Using Spring's Cachable annotation on methods that returns Hibernate objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, spring-roo

I've setup Memcached yesterday and eventually got Spring `@Cachable` annotation working ...

This block of code caches perfectly:

```
@Component("CacheProcessor")
public class CacheProcessor {
    @Cacheable(value = "defaultCache", key="'dateTime-'.concat(#anything)")
    public String getDateTime2(String anything) {
        Date d = new Date();
        String response = Long.toString(d.getTime());
        return response;
    }
}
```

I tried caching methods which are called for each request:

```
@org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable(value="defaultCache", key="username")
public static List<Session> findSessionByUserName(String username) {

    String hql = "SELECT o FROM Session AS o WHERE o.username=:username";
    TypedQuery<Session> query = Session.entityManager().createQuery(hql, Session.class);
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    return query.getResultList();

}
```

... but I'm greeted with a stacktrace instead of a cached result:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Post-processor tried to replace bean instance of type [com.ahp.core.model.Session] with (proxy) object of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66] - not supported for aspect-configured classes!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.checkExposedObject(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.configureBean(AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aj:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj:91)
    at com.ahp.core.model.Session.<init>(Session.java:20)
    at com.ahp.core.model.Session.entityManager_aroundBody0(Session.java:57)
    at com.ahp.core.model.Session.entityManager(Session.java:1)
    at com.ahp.core.processor.AccountProcessor.validateSession(AccountProcessor.java:545)
    at com.ahp.core.processor.WarehouseProcessor.consume(WarehouseProcessor.java:93)
    at com.ahp.core.processor.WarehouseProcessor.consume(WarehouseProcessor.java:1)
    at com.ahp.messaging.processor.AbstractRPCConsumer.onMessage(AbstractRPCConsumer.java:32)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1241)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In case it helps, here's a snippet of the Session class, it was generated by Spring Roo, then using Push-In refactor, I got rid of all the AspectJ so now it's just a single Java class:

```
@Entity
@Configurable
//@RooJavaBean
//@RooToString
//@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Session {

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager entityManager;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "qusername")
    private String username;

    ....
```

If I remove the `Configurable` annotation, the entity manager doesn't get injected and an `IllegalStateException` is thrown.

```
    public static final EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new Session().entityManager;
        if (em == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }
```

How do I get caching working on `aspect-configured` classes?

If it's not possible, what would be the procedure for making it work without aspects (assuming that would make it cachable)?

**Working Solution**

Had to create a SessionService interface:

```
@RooService(domainTypes = {Session.class })
public interface SessionService {
    public List<Session> findSessionByUserName(String username);
}
```

SessionServiceImpl:

```
@Component
public class SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService {
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value="defaultCache", key="#username")
    public List<Session> findSessionByUserName(String username) {
        return Session.findSessionByUserName(username);
    }
}
```

Had to modify the Session class to be serializable as well as returned the Roo annotations.

```
@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@Configurable
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Session implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```

Then using my autowired SessionService:

```
@Autowired
SessionService sessionService;
```

I can now make use of the Cache:

```
sessionService.findSessionByUserName(...)
```

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the way you can retrieve the currently logged-in user, I had the same problem. I did it this way, in-case it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851337/spring-spring-cache-not-working

Comment: Your solution would work if I was using Spring Security and the security check was done by Spring Security. I'm trying to solve caching hibernate objects in general since I need to cache other objects which are getting hit 10000 times per minute

Comment: Oh...Ok...  Redis seems like a good option, instead of this... Is what I think..

Comment: Long-term, I'll move those tables to a Redis DB, short term I'm trying to kill off some bottlnecks. Since I'm already implementing Memcached to cache certain API calls, I might as well piggy-back on that infrastructure.

Comment: Redis is an advanced version of memcached...and all it takes is 50 lines to achieve what you want... I don't understand your motivation to move it to memcached now.

Comment: How easy is it to replace Memcached with Redis, will the `@Cacheable` annotation continue to work as it currently does with Memcached? 
Redis does look like a better option in the cases where I'm trying to cache generated documents that are greater than 1MB.

Comment: Check this pastebin, I have posted what all you would requite, I can assist you in 1 hour after lunchbreak if you have doubts. : http://pastebin.com/1VCcpi1Q

Comment: I'll take it for a spin later today, if I get stuck, I'll post another question specifically around Redis and Spring Cache. Thanks @WeareBorg

Comment: Sure... I just had a thought, that in-case if those are Spring-Security session objects you are trying to cache, dont forget session expires with a timeout as mentioned in your web.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add cache to static method (the way that is done in Roo ActiveRecord pattern). You must configure the cache layer on bean methods (non-static).

An approach could be create a Service Layer between Entity layer and Web layers using Roo generation (take a look on [Roo documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RC1/reference/html/base-layers.html#service-layer)). This utility creates Spring beans which call to Roo entity methods and modify the Contollers methods to use it. So you can annotate the methods of this Service-Bean with `@Cacheable` to use cache wherever you need it.

Good luck!

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should wrap the static call in a Bean that I then Autowire and then use the Autowired Bean instead of the static method and then move the Cachable annotation to the Autowired Bean?

Comment: Yes... If you use the Roo command ``service``, Roo modifies controller's _.aj_ files to use the new ``service`` but only if you left the Entity in _Roo way_ (uncomment  Roo annotations)

Comment: Only got to tinker further with it now, after adding the `@RooService` annotation, it was fairly simple to get it working. Posted my solution in case anyone else gets stuck. Thanks for the awesome answer @jmvivo